# search password with security find-internet-password based on `where`

Tags: security, password

From the macos terminal, I would like to be able to find an internet password based on the `Where` field and i cant find a way to do that.

[image]

From the manual of the [security](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/security/) utility , i cant find anything thats related to that and if i try the `-s server` option, it doesnt work.

My usecase is to have multiple entries with the same Name/Kind/Account and a different `Where`, for example i would have two entries and the only difference would be

- `https://foo.bar/v1/login`
- `https://foo.bar/v2/login`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Is your question about filling in passwords in Safari? Which manual you are referring to, and where have you tried the `-s server` option?

Comment: it all made sense in my mind when i wrote the question :D I've updated it to say that im looking for a terminal solution and im referring to the `security` command line utility.